# Firebase Analytics calculation of User counts (Daily/Weekly/Monthly Active Users)

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

Firebase Analytics reports data w.r.t. Daily/Weekly/Monthly Active Users.

Few questions:
(1) Dashboard:
Projecting the Daily Active Users to a month, does not match the value shown in Firebase Dashboard.

For e.g. if Daily Active Users is 30K, then Firebase shows the corresponding Monthly Active Users as 150K.
Does it imply that there were 30K users in last 7 days, and 120K in the preceding 21days?
Not sure why isn't it 30 days x 30K = 900K.

(2) On selecting Firebase > Events > Select_Content > App version
Last 7 days: shows approx 100K
Last 30 days: shows approx 140K
Does it imply that in the 21 day period only 40K User sessions occurred, while the App usage went up drastically in last 7 days?

Please help clarify.

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 17):

The Active Users report in the Firebase dashboard is showing counts of users in the *past* 30, 7 and 1 day. The values are not projected, but rather based on user engagement that has been measured over those periods. The other thing to keep in mind is for each of those periods, it's the count of *unique* users over the entire period.

So, for example, if your seeing 150K Monthly Active Users (which is defined [here as 30-day active users](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317517?authuser=0#active-users)), that tells you you've had 150K unique users engage with your App in the last 30-day period. If you're seeing 30K Daily Active users, that tells you you had 30K unique users yesterday, and 120K *different* unique users from the 29 days before yesterday.

If the same user engages with your App more than once in the period, they only count as one. Out of your 30K users from yesterday, a number of those would have presumably engaged in the 29 days before that, so it's expected that your Monthly Active Users would be less than your Daily Active Users x 30 days. How much lower would depend on the specifics of your app, but the closer those numbers are, the more frequently the same users are returning to your App over the 30 days, which is positive in terms of user <strike>engagement</strike> retention.

Comment: Thanks @Evan, it makes sense to me. Could u please put a link about explaining the Firebase Engagement term? I tried but couldn't find any doc explain this word

Comment: @Nguyen this post on The Firebase Blog describes what they mean by "user engagement" and goes into some detail about how it's measured https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/12/new-changes-sessions-user-engagement.html.

Just to note, when Firebase says "user engagement" they are referring to how long users are interacting with the app. I don't think the 30-, 7- and 1- day metrics depend on any minimum engagement, those reflect _any_ user interaction with the app, however long or short that may be.

Comment: @Nguyen actually, I was using the term "user engagement" incorrectly in my original answer. If your Daily Active Users and Monthly Active Users numbers are close, that really reflects good user _retention_ - i.e. the same users are using the app many times over the 30-day period. I've edited my answer for clarity.

Comment: @EvanKirkwood Can i be certain that the daily active user count shown in the dashboard is the count of UNIQUE users that interact with the app? 
Here in the Firebase documentation, it doesn't mention about the unique count, only mentions that an active user logs a user_engagement event. (https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317517?hl=en)