# What's the difference between Google Analytics "active users" and Firebase "active users"?

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics

Due to Google Analytics is sunsetting i have to migrate my analytics from GA to Firebase, but I found difference between the two data calculated between the two platforms.

For Example my mobile app "*Active users*" based on **Google Analytics**

[Google Analytics Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGH5e.png)

**1 day: 135**

**7 day: 653**

**28 day: 2,224**

but my "*Active users*" based on **Firebase** is

[Firebase Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmmgM.png)

**1 day: 1.6 k**

**7 day: 6.6 k**

**28 day: 17 k**

is there a difference in the algorithm or how the two platforms differentiate or identify their active users?

Answer (score 0):

In Firebase what you are referring to as **Active Users** are the user engagement measurement values that are based on a period of either 1, 7 and 30 Days.

See the answer above that goes more into detail : [Firebase Analytics calculation of User counts (Daily/Weekly/Monthly Active Users)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48816818/firebase-analytics-calculation-of-user-counts-daily-weekly-monthly-active-users)

Comment: thanks for the insight, so what do you think make FA different to GA? is it because of the strict value on how they decide about the user engagement?

Comment: @AkbarPamungkas I am sure they have updated how they define user engagement.